# Force close when trying to take EditText value into float variable

Tags: java, android

My app force closes when I tried to assign an edit text value to float.
here's the code.
 I also tried Float.parseFloat() method instead of Float.valueOf(). 
If I take off my getETvalue() method then the app works. Please help

```
package com.example.aviator_18;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    float Remaining,Departure,TotUplift,SG,DiscResult;
    int CalUpliftResult;
    TextView RemainingTV,DepartureTV,UpliftTV,SGtv,CalcUpliftTV,DiscrepancyTV;
    EditText RemainingET,DepartureET,TotUpliftET,SGet,CalcUpliftET,DiscrepancyET;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupView();
        getETvalue();
        evaluation();
        CalcUpliftTV.setText(String.valueOf(CalUpliftResult));
        DiscrepancyTV.setText(String.valueOf(DiscResult));


    }

    private void getETvalue() {
        String a,b,c,d,e;
        Remaining=Float.valueOf(RemainingET.getText().toString());
        Departure=Float.valueOf(DepartureET.getText().toString());
        TotUplift=Float.valueOf(TotUpliftET.getText().toString());
        SG=Float.valueOf(SGet.getText().toString());



    }

    private void evaluation() {


        CalUpliftResult=Math.round(TotUplift*SG);
        DiscResult=((Departure-Remaining-CalUpliftResult)/CalUpliftResult)*100;

    }

    private void setupView() {
        RemainingET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.remainingET);
        DepartureET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.departureET);
        TotUpliftET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TotalUpliftET);
        SGet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.SGet);

        CalcUpliftTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CalUpliftResult);
        DiscrepancyTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.discResult);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: My whole app crashes before even I give an input. So I dont think its that the input is non parsable

Comment: Thank you, when I included the exception handling the app atleast starts now.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was indeed an exception due to improper parsing. I put the getETvalue() function inside a buttons onclick so that the edit texts values are parsed to float only after valid data is entered into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the string can be parsed to a float.
You can add try - catch

```
try {
   Remaining=Float.parseFloat(RemainingET.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Float.valueOf` will convert a string value that contains a float number in the form of string. But if the string contains anything that cannot be parsed into a float, then this method will throw `NumberFormatException`

Like:

`float f = Float.valueOf("12.35")  //this is correct`

While

`float f = Float.valueOf("abcd") //this is incorrect`

which causes force close as it must be throwing `NumberFormatException`

[From the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

***ValueOf***

```
public static Float valueOf(String s)
                     throws NumberFormatException
Returns a Float object holding the float value represented by the argument string s.

Throws:
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable number.
```